# Rails / RSpec: How to test Rails action with third party API?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, unit-testing, rspec

```
class SessionsController < ApplicationController::Base  
  def create
      result = verify_sms_code(params[:session][:phone], params[:session][:code]
       if result['code'] == 200
         render json: {code: 200, msg: 'success'}
       else
         render json: {code: 404, msg: 'failed'}
       end
    end
end
```

The `verify_sms_code` method invokes third party API from network, the API returns JSON result for validation short message.

How can I test create action? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can stub method making external api call i.e verify_sms_code in your case. You can write something like

```
SessionsController.any_instance.stub(:verify_sms_code).and_return({code: 200, data: ''})
```

When you write above code whenever you use verify_sms_code inside SessionsController it will return the hash that you provide i.e `{code: 200, data: ''}`

If you are using rspec 3 and above, you can mock `verify_sms_code` as following inside controller.

```
allow(controller).to receive(:verify_sms_code).and_return({code: 200, data: ''})
```

Reference link:

https://www.relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-mocks/v/2-6/docs/method-stubs/stub-on-any-instance-of-a-class

http://rspec.info/documentation/3.4/rspec-mocks/

There are also other ways to mock. Check below link

https://robots.thoughtbot.com/how-to-stub-external-services-in-tests

Example:

```
it "does something" do   
  SessionsController.any_instance.stub(:verify_sms_code).and_return({code: 200, data: "success data"})
end

it "does other thing" do 
   SessionsController.any_instance.stub(:verify_sms_code).and_return({code: 404, data: "error data"})
end
```

Comment: but how to change the return value? For some reason, I want to return {code:404}  in other examples , but `SessionsController.any_instance.stub(:verify_sms_code).and_return({code: 200, data: ''}) ` returns {code: 200, data:""} in all examples

Comment: @Ryman1981 updated my answer with example. You have to stub it on per example bases if you need to return different response inside different examples

Comment: As of RSpec 3.3 , any_instance is deprecated and not recommended. I use the `allow(controller).to receive(:verify_sms_code).and_return({code: 200, data: 'success data'}, {code: 404, data: 'error data'})` but it only returns first response

Comment: Thanks for the info. I will update my answer with the new method for rspec 3.3

Answer (score 0):

I use the VCR gem for testing actions that make API calls.
It lets you record API responses to use them in tests.

https://github.com/vcr/vcr

Answer (score 0):

I use [webmock](https://github.com/bblimke/webmock) and like it quite a lot. I get a lot of control over headers, params, return content, return headers, return status, etc. But, not a lot of overhead.

I put all of my `stub_requests` into a shared set of files then include them en masse via `rails_helper.rb`. That way, I can reuse my `stub_requests` throughout my test suite.